# why does this not compile if operator delete has no implementation

Tags: c++

why does this not compile if operator delete has no implementation?

---

```
class A
{ 
public: 
    virtual ~A(){ } 
private: 
    void operator delete(void *p); 
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
}
```

compile with g++, get below error:

undefined reference to `A::operator delete(void*)'

if either give it an empty implementation for operator delete

```
class A
{ 
public: 
    virtual ~A(){ } 
private: 
    void operator delete(void *p) {}
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
}
```

or remove the "virtual"

```
class A
{ 
public: 
    ~A(){ } 
private: 
    void operator delete(void *p); 
};

int main() 
{
    A a;
}
```

both compile successfully.

How to explain this?

Comment: It is a linker error, not a compiler error. But why would you expect the code not to produce an error? A function that doesn't exist is being called.

Comment: I don't expect to not produce an error, I am just thinking how to explain why it won't link, I am learning c++ and see such a question somewhere else.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think his question is based on the fact he's not invoking it in *any* of these , so why does the former fail to link while the latter seems to ignore the lack of implementation simply by removing `virtual` from a destructor decl. You said "A function that doesn't exist is being called". I think he wants to know from where/how that call is instigated?

Comment: According to my reading of the standard, the code is supposed to be invalid even if you remove the `virtual`.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah, that is my question.

Comment: @Brian the fact is that it can compile/link if I remove the virtual.

Comment: I think a class has virtual fucntion need have Vptr table,So it need an implementation. Anyway this code is ill-form

Comment: @RonTang, yes, usually people don't write code in this style, this is just an interview question to check how interviewer understand the virtual and operator delete override is working here.

Comment: @FrankZhang oh,god.~a()? ~A()!!!Destructor with the same name as the class. No one can be compiled......

Comment: @RonTang, sorry, a typo, updated.

Comment: It's funny that Ideone will not complain in any of these situations http://ideone.com/rMRyX1

Comment: Very weird.  When ~A has virtual, it actually does call delete!

Comment: The delete is not actually called in 'main' here since the only use of the dtor ~A is for variable 'a' which is auto. When you make the the dtor virtual, the compiler must create a "general" dtor for the virtual mechanism, which will contain a call to operator delete. Likewise if you make ~A non-inline (but still empty) it will contain a call to operator delete, and it won't link.

Comment: ok, I looked at the assembly language output.  Seems when you do virtual ~A, it creates two destructors.  One is a "scalar deleting destructor" and the other is the normal destructor (this is visual studio; g++ does similar but by different names).  "scalar deleting destructor" is called when you do call delete.  For whatever reason, "scalar deleting destructor" gets generated even if you don't call delete.  "scalar deleting destructor" forwards to operator delete.

Comment: When you don't do virtual ~A, it doesn't create the scalar deleting destructor.  It seems the compiler should be smart enough not to generate the scalar deleting destructor if it's not being used... but that's not the case.

Comment: @thang Thanks for the detailed answer, wanna vote for useful comments but not find the button...

Comment: @Quest not sure what tricky thing the online ide is doing, but g++ will complain, I am using g++ in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a huge difference between:

```
void operator delete(void *p);
```

and

```
void operator delete(void *p) {}
```

The former simply *declares* the function; the latter *defines* it. When you declare a function, you're basically just saying "there is a function, and here are the types of its arguments and its return value", but when you define a function, you are writing down the code that actually comprises the function. A function defined with an empty pair of braces does nothing; a function declared but not defined might do anything at all (you can't know until you see the definition). Obviously, a function cannot be called unless it has been defined. Less obviously, a function cannot have its address taken unless it has been defined. Obviously, both of these statements imply that if you call a function or take the address of a function, and you have failed to define it, your program is ill-formed.

Generally, the result of failing to define something that needs a definition is a linker error. That's because when you use something in a way that requires a definition, the compiler creates a symbol that tells the linker to insert the address in the required location once it finds the definition. If the linker can't find the definition (and hence the address), then it can't complete its job.

The C++ standard has an arcane set of rules that basically tell you under what conditions a function is *required* to be defined. Sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't. A trivial example:

```
int f();
int main() {}
```

This is fine; the function `f` is never called, implicitly or explicitly; its address is never taken; it doesn't even have a *chance* of being called. Therefore, this program will compile, even though `f` is not defined.

According to the standard, a function must be defined if it is *odr-used*. The standard has the following to say about `operator delete` ([basic.def.odr]/3):

> ... A non-placement allocation or deallocation function for
>   a class is odr-used by the definition of a constructor of that class. A non-placement deallocation function for
>   a class is odr-used by the definition of the destructor of that class, or by being selected by the lookup at the
>   point of definition of a virtual destructor (12.4). (footnote 26)...

Therefore: if your class has a constructor or destructor defined, it odr-uses your `operator delete`. Therefore, it doesn't matter whether your destructor is virtual or not; your program is ill-formed without a definition of `operator delete`, since you defined a destructor. [1]

Now, you might ask why your compiler and linker don't complain when the destructor is non-virtual. Well, toolchains sometimes accept code even when they are supposed to reject it. In this particular case, if the destructor is not virtual, then nothing your program actually needs the address of `operator delete`, so the linker won't complain if you never define it. But when you make the destructor virtual, because lookup of deallocation functions is based on the dynamic type of the object being deallocated, there needs to be a vtable entry for the deallocation function, implying that its address must be known. Hence the link error. (Again, I want to reiterate that even though your compiler and linker accept the code when the destructor is non-virtual, it's still ill-formed code by my reading of the standard.)

[1] Note that as long as you actually create an object of type `A`, it's impossible for there not to be a definition of the constructor and destructor, even if you didn't define them yourself; that is, the compiler will generate the definition implicitly.)

Comment: Great long answer, but it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @thang What part of the question is not addressed?

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the detailed information. I wanna vote your answer up but my reputation is not enough at this time. Anyway, it is really good for me to learn.

Comment: @Brian: You do not answer why the operator is needed at all.

Comment: @sbi I think I made it clear that the definition is needed because the function is odr-used. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Brian: You are right. I missed that. TBH, though, it is one paragraph in this incredibly long answer that actually explains what's going on: _"Therefore: if your class has a constructor or destructor defined..."_ I simply missed it. Actually, would you cut this long answer to this paragraph and the two before (and maybe the one after), it would be just as relevant and twice as helpful.